# popup can't close (IBAction not working)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, popup, xib

I use a popup system that I found here : https://blog.typpz.com/2013/12/09/ios-sdk-create-a-pop-up-window/

And after following the guide step by step everything works except the closing button. I tried to link it in various ways but nothing works.

Does anyone know what I do wrong ?

here is my code:

PopUpController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface PopUpViewController : UIViewController


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *popUpView;

- (void)showInView:(UIView *)aView animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (IBAction)closePopup:(id)sender;


@end
```

PopUpController.m:

```
#import "PopUpViewController.h"

@interface PopUpViewController ()

@end

@implementation PopUpViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor]     colorWithAlphaComponent:.6];
self.popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
self.popUpView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
self.popUpView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
self.popUpView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma animation

- (void)showAnimate
{
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
self.view.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
    self.view.alpha = 1;
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
}];
}

- (void)removeAnimate
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}];
}



- (void)showInView:(UIView *)aView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[aView addSubview:self.view];
if (animated) {
    [self showAnimate];
}
}

- (IBAction)closePopup:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"closing...");
[self removeAnimate];
}


@end
```

NOTE: I don't even get the NSLog closing... on my console when I click the closing button

here is a screenshot of my .xib file:

[image: xib screenshot]

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Have you made a connection right (Now connect the popUpView outlet to the view in the .xib file) . . . from your reference

Comment: I just tried to relink the view and linking to the main view nothing change.. (There is only the button that doesn't work. the popup prompt fine)

Comment: To make a subView actions functional ... you have to add as a child view controller. So to make close popup functional ... you need to add the PopViewController as a child view controller to the viewController from where you want to show the popup.

Comment: Thanks @NisarAhmad ! It was this I added this line : 
    [self addChildViewController:subV]; and it worked.

Comment: glade to help you